# stream.Writable: how to use CallBack while defining the prototype._write method?

Tags: node.js

In this code:

```
wStream = require("stream").Writable,
logStream = function logStream () {
                this.file = logfile;
                wStream.call(this);
            };

require("util").inherits(logStream, wStream);
logStream.prototype._write = function logStream_write (data, enc, cb) {
    fs.appendFile(this.file, data, 'utf-8', function WatchLogErr(err) {
       if (err) {throw Error(err);}
    });
    //cb(data);
    cb();
};

const log = new logStream();
```

I want to know how can I use the **cb** and where exactly to call it from?
Could I have some examples please to understand how it can be useful. 
trying to wrap my head around stream.Writable api methods.

Is it possible to pass an argument in this cb? what additional logic do i have to add in order to use this cb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `cb()`, it tells writer that you've successfully processed the data and ready to process next chunk. Then writer will send you more data in `_write` method if there is any data.

If you don't call `cb()` but there is more data available, writer will put all incoming data in internal buffer and wait for you to call `cb()`.

In your example, you are calling callback before appending is finished. There is a chance that `fs.appendFile` will be called again even before the previous appending is finished. This might give you undesired result. So the right way is to call it inside `fs.appendFile` callback:

```
logStream.prototype._write = function logStream_write (data, enc, cb) {
    fs.appendFile(this.file, data, 'utf-8', function WatchLogErr(err) {
       cb(err)
    });
};
```

as you noticed, `cb` take only one argument that is error object. Passing error object in cb will emit `error` event on writer stream.

Comment: You are right. asynchronously fs might be executing later than cb so cb should be inside. 
cb by design shouldn't have been here,looks more vestigial.
When err could be handled with an if statement.

Comment: does it make sense to do a try catch and do a log.end() in the catch block?

Comment: `try--catch` won't be able to catch the error that occurred in asynchronous block. You have to listen `error` event and put `log.end()` there.